# Moving the jBullet collision body to with the player object

Tags: java, collision-detection, movement, bullet-physics

I am trying to update the location of the rigid body for a player class, as my player moves around I would like the collision body to also move with the player object (currently represented as a cube).  Below is my current update method for when I want to update the xyz coords, but I am pretty sure I am not able to update the origin coords? :

```
    public void Update(float pX, float pY, float pZ) {
    posX = pX;
    posY = pY;
    posZ = pZ;

    //update the playerCube transform for the rigid body
    cubeTransform.origin.x = posX;
    cubeTransform.origin.y = posY;
    cubeTransform.origin.z = posZ;

    cubeRigidBody.getMotionState().setWorldTransform(cubeTransform);

    processTransformMatrix(cubeTransform);
    }
```

I do not have rotation updated, as I do not actually want/need the player body to rotate at all currently.  However, in the final game this will be put in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the physics object a kinematic object. See [Bullet Physics Manual](http://www.bulletphysics.com/ftp/pub/test/physics/Bullet_User_Manual.pdf) for more information. Bullet Physics ask every frame the current transformation from kinematic objects. You need your own MotionState implementation for that. Mine is as simple as this:

```
public class KinematicMotionState extends MotionState {
    private Transform worldTransform;

    public KinematicMotionState() {
        worldTransform = new Transform();
        worldTransform.setIdentity();
    }

    @Override
    public Transform getWorldTransform(Transform out) {
        out.set(worldTransform);
        return out;
    }

    @Override
    public void setWorldTransform(Transform worldTrans) {
        worldTransform.set(worldTrans);
    }
}
```

In addition you must tell the rigid body that it's a kinematic object:

```
rigidBody.setCollisionFlags(rigidBody.getCollisionFlags() | CollisionFlags.KINEMATIC_OBJECT);
rigidBody.setActivationState(CollisionObject.DISABLE_DEACTIVATION);
```

And then updating the transformation of the kinematic object:

```
Transform transform = new Transform();
transform.setIdentity();
transform.origin.set(x, y, z);
motionState.setWorldTransform(transform);
```

Comment: That is so simple!  I had looked through the Bullet Physics manual a bit before posting, but I guess I just didn't know what I was looking for!  This was super helpful thank you again msell!

Comment: Isn't this just setting the position? What happens when something collides?